# How do you boot into EFI settings on an x86-64 MacBook Pro from 2010?

Tags: mac, boot, efi

I'd like to get to the EFI settings page on my MacBook Pro.  I haven't been able to find the keyboard sequence required to boot into this mode...is this still an option on recent MacBook Pro's or do I need to boot from the OS CD to access EFI via a utility ?

Thanks,

Scott

Comment: Any chance you could mark this question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered installing rEFIt?  I didn't even think there was a way/reason to do so.  Someone else will likely provide the real answer, but ReFIT may take care of your needs until then.  I use it every day (that I use my computer), and it works great.

Comment: It's called rEFIt.

Comment: Great! Does this flash the EFI firmware or is it loaded from disk after POST ?

Comment: I believe it's loaded from the disk, you can still access the original EFI from Apple, and remove rEFIt if you desire.